# How can I move spaces between external monitors in Mavericks?

Tags: macos, display, spaces, mission-control

I have a new (late 2013) MBP that I use with an external monitor. Annoyingly, when I plug/unplug the monitor, arbitrary spaces end up being fixed to either the internal or external monitor. Going to mission control doesn't appear to let me move spaces from one monitor to another, so I have to manually shuffle around each window. Is there a keyboard shortcut (or something) I'm missing to move spaces between monitors?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried moving a non-active space? because i can only move a space which is not active at the moment.

Comment: The tip above is the correct answer. If you make it to an actual answer, I'll approve it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can only move spaces which are non-active.

For example, lets say you have spaces 1 and 2. If space 1 is active, you can not move it. You first have to select space 2 then you can move space 1 to a different monitor.

Comment: is this still valid? how do you do the actual moving?

Answer (score 2):

[TotalSpaces](http://totalspaces.binaryage.com) allows you to assign spaces and their contents to specific monitors.

[image]

Comment: It seems your answer stops mid-post. Could you please fix that?

Comment: From what I can tell, it doesn't actually let you assign spaces to displays, or move them between displays.

Comment: It also requires you to disable System Integrity Protection. https://totalspaces.binaryage.com/sip-details